# UX principles for displaying "Cookies Policy" on websites

Tags: usability, interaction-design, ux-integration

While displaying cookies information on website, have found some

- a display on top of the page, with "close" icon or "OK" button
- a display on the bottom as fixed layout having "Close" icon or "OK" button
- a display with modal pop-up having short details with "Close" icon or "OK" button or "Close" text.

Do we really need usability focus on displaying the "Cookies Policy"?

What will be the best layout, if usability comes into a picture?

Comment: @JonW before adding as a [Duplicate] questions, please go through the purpose of the questions. I have mentioned for the layout of the design. It is nothing to do with the contents which have to display. My questions is purely based on designs and usability; not in terms of content.

Comment: Well your question is very broad and opinion based if left open, so I closed it and linked to a canonical page covering very similar issues. But as you have written it there is no single correct answer, just subjective opinions.